# MemberMouse Registration Date plus 24 hours

Tags: php, wordpress, date, membership

I am working on a MemberMouse subscription Wordpress website. On a specific user page, I need to display the time of the registration date plus 24 hours. For example, if registration date is: Jul 24, 2017 12:34 pm, I want to display: Jul 25, 2017 12:34 pm.

```
<?php
$datee= date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime("[MM_Member_Data 
name='registrationDate']+ 10 hours"));
?>

Access until: <?php  echo $datee; ?>
```

By the way, the SmartTag "[MM_Member_Data 
    name='registrationDate']" gives out for example: Jul 24, 2017 12:34 pm.

I tried above code to get registration date, but getting error.

Any solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aron

Comment: couldn't you just use `[MM_Member_Data 
name='expirationDate']` ?

Comment: the also have a support area were they can probably help you out  http://support.membermouse.com/support/discussions

Comment: The Tag only gives back the registration date, however I am trying to add 24 hours on the registration date. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Are you sure the SmartTag is even parsed in there? SomeText + 10 hours is just false and will not return a valid date instance.
Parse the tag first and then add 36000 or 86400 to it (dates in php are just integer unix timestamps)

Comment: @Mastacheata Oh thanks for the info. So first I need to parse the tag and refer it in the function or can I already include it in the strtotime() parse it there and add 36000 to it? A sample would be more than great, sorry just in the learning phase with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest code would look somewhat like this and keep your original idea of just processing the shortcode inline.

```
<?php
$datee= date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime(do_shortcode("[MM_Member_Data name='registrationDate'] + 10 hours")));
?>

Access until: <?php echo $datee; ?>
```

However I would rather use the clean approach and do things seperately (plus: I got no idea what format the registrationDate shortcode is. Is that a unix timestamp or a string formatted date/time?)

```
<?php
// let's assume for a minute that $registrationDate will be a php date aka unix timestamp
// if it's not, you'll have to first run this through strtotime again, i.e.:
// $registrationDate = strtotime(do_shortcode("[MM_Member_Data name='registrationDate']"));

$registrationDate = do_shortcode("[MM_Member_Data name='registrationDate']");
$datee = date("F j, Y g:i a", $registrationDate + 36000);
?>

Access until: <?php echo $datee; ?>
```